# Update Dotnet Core Projects with new dotnet new Template Version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have a question surrounding dotnet templates and if there is a way to update existing projects created using dotnet new with a custom template with updates made to the template.

What I am trying to do:

- I currently have a dotnet new template that has been used to create multiple asp.net microservice projects being developed by multiple team members. This initial template is a custom template with some folder structuring and common files across the services.
- I want to be able to update the dotnet new template adding new folders/files/make changes to some of the files inside the template (Program.cs/Startup.cs etc) and then apply these changes across the projects that have already been created.

From what I have searched so far I havent found a way to do this within the dotnet template or I'm not sure exactly how this could work so am also open to other solutions to achieve the kind of result described above using different tools/methods for updating these projects. Also dont mind if I would need to restructure current projects to work in a different way that would allow these kinds of updates in the future

Thanks for your help in advance,

Callum

Comment: In theory copier can do that, but I haven't personally got it working https://copier.readthedocs.io/en/stable/updating/

Answer (score 1):

> If there is a way to update existing projects created using dotnet new with a custom template with updates made to the template

I think the answer is a solid "no". There's no (built-in) way to take an existing project and update it based on an updated template.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the template again in the target directory using the same parameters you used to generate it in the first place, plus `--force` to overwrite everything.

e.g.

```bash
cd your-generated-project/
dotnet new <yourtemplate> <yourparams> --force
```

2. Use git to stage the changes you want to apply to the generated project.

[git add --patch](https://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-add/) is particularly good for this